# How do I set the Paypal Authorization Id when creating a new Sales Order in Netsuite

Tags: php, api, paypal, netsuite

I am attempted to create a new Sales Order in Netsuite using PHPtoolkip_v2010.php and add a authorization id to its payment method.

I can create the Sales Order and set the payment method to PayPal, but I am unable to set the AuthId.  If I try to set the Transaction Id I'm successful, but as soon as I switch the code to do an auth it fails.

Here's a snippet of the code I'm trying:

```
$sales_order_data = array(
    'entity'=> new nsRecordRef(array('internalId' => $customer_id)),
    'tranDate'=>date('c', strtotime($order_date)),
    'itemList'=>array('item'=>array()),
);

//...

$sales_order_data['paymentMethod'] = array('internalId'=>7);

//$sales_order_data['payPalTranId'] = $paypal_transaction_id;
$sales_order_data['paypalAuthId'] = $paypal_transaction_id;

$sales_order = new nsComplexObject('SalesOrder', $sales_order_data);
$new_sales_order = $ns->add($sales_order);
```

If I get an existing Paypal order through the API and `var_dump` it I see the fields `payPalTranId` and `paypalAuthId` are set.  Notice that the seconds P in Paypal is capitalized for the TranId but not for the AuthId.  But I have tried both capped and uncapped for AuthId with no results.

Comment: What error do you get?  Is there anything in the Web Services Usage Log in Netsuite?

Comment: @Craig No error is returned.  The Log shows the request and response without error and status "FINISHED".

Comment: Have you tried with the latest PHPtoolkit 2011.2? BTW, it looks like the inconsistent caps are correct according to the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what I wanted to do was impossible.

I've found this statement on from [Celigo](http://www.celigo.com/help/magento/magento-reference/payment-methods/), a company that specializes in integrating Magento with Netsuite.

> Both authorization and capture must be done on the Magento side.
>   NetSuite does not facilitate capture of payments that have been
>   authorized outside NetSuite. The NetSuite field that needs to be set
>   to indicate the authorization status, ‘PayPal Status’, is read-only
>   and thus cannot be set. The transaction cannot be processed unless
>   this field is set.

While they don't explicitly state that I can't set the AuthId, my goal in doing so was to authroize the payment outside of Netsuite and capture within.  If that's not possible,  then setting the AuthId is pointless for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got it straightened out and sucessfully. 
Did you try to enable the "Override PayPal Settings " field? 
I am trying to bring in PayPal information from external webstore and authid, looking at this field as reading your posting.

Comment: This is more of a comment/questions than answer. Consider this type of response for the comments below the poster's question.

Comment: user3750350 - Were you able to bring in the PayPal Information from the External WebStore?  Auth ID and all.  We are having the same issues and would like to hear how  you accomplished this task if you don't mind.  Thanks.